# replace or remove GPG signature on RPM

Tags: centos, rpm, gpg

Is there a way to remove or replace an existing GPG signature on an RPM?

I am placing a few obscure RPMs on an internal repo we use for supplementary rhel/centos packages.  A few of those RPMs are already signed.  I would like to remove those signatures and resign them with a GPG signature we use for our local repo.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Simply (re-) [sign](http://www.rpm.org/max-rpm/rpm.8.html) the packages with your own key...

```
rpm --addsign package.rpm
```

The `--addsign` option generates and inserts new signatures for each package. Any existing signatures will be discarded.

The `--resign` option generates and appends signatures for the listed packages while preserving the existing signatures.

If you had imported the public key you can validate the new signature

```
rpm --checksig -v package.rpm
```

You should see the phrase `Good signature from "Your Name"` in the output.

AFAIK removing signatures isn't supported.

Comment: slight clarification for --resign, it will force resign if a key with the same sig exists or does not exist, and for --addsign, existing signatures are not automatically discarded if the signature you're trying to sign with is the same (or even different it seems) from the existing signature, i.e. --resign is basically the equivalent of force sign and overwrite any existing signatures.

Answer (score 2):

HBruijn's answer is largely correct and useful but, for completeness, removing signatures *is* supported, using the `rpmsign --delsign package.rpm`.